# Requests in Python doesn't work after installation package

Tags: python, http, python-requests, package

So I've installed Python requests using these methods:

`$ git clone git://github.com/requests/requests.git`

`$ curl -OL https://github.com/requests/requests/tarball/master`

`$ cd requests
$ pip install .`

`pip install requests`

```
C:\Users\anonr>pip list
Package    Version
---------- --------
certifi    2019.3.9
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.8
pip        19.0.3
requests   2.21.0
setuptools 40.8.0
urllib3    1.24.1
```

Which I found here:

> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/

**And I have requests on my packages in Python27/lib/site-packages/requests**

But when I try to use it on a script with `import requests;` it doesn't work.

Like I did not install it at all.

Does any one know how to fix this problem? I tried reinstalling and installing again but still...

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use virtual environment? Maybe problem is because you do not have installed requests package in virtual environment.

Comment: No I dont use virtual enviroment just windows

Comment: I followed the steps and it works fine for me. If you are using PyCharm, PyCharm automatically create virtual environment.

Comment: Yes I use Pycharm. I tried uninstalling Python to Pythhon 37-32. And pip3 install requests. All worked but when I try to import requests still doesnt work...

Comment: Do you run `pip install requests` in cmd?

Comment: Yeah I run it on cmd windows.

Comment: The problem is that you do not install requests in your project environment. Open the terminal in your Pycharm and there you have to run`pip install requests`.

Comment: Oh you mean in /Pycharm projects? I should do again pip install requests? I did and it says in three lines which they start with "requeriment allready satisfied"

Comment: Check if you have installed requests library in your pycharm project. In PyCharm you go under file>settings>Project:your_project_name>Project Interpreter, if there is no requests library this mean that you did not install it in your project enviroment.

Comment: If you trying to import like this `import requests;`, mybe this is the problem. Import it without ; (`import requests`)

Comment: Yes There is not requests in my project interpreter. How do I install it there?

Comment: Pycharm use virtual environment for every project that you have created. Read something about virtual environment in python, it will save you a lot of time if you will understand how it works. Folow this steps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this method:

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a standard `pip` install?

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: Are you sure the install/site-packages name and the import name have matching capitalization?

Comment: Yeah I can see that both have name "requests"

Comment: does the install work? try using `sudo` if it doesn't

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize you were on windows